# Como detectar conexão com a internet no ionic?

Tags: ionic, ionic3

Estou usando o Ionic 3 junto com o plugin network do ionic, consigo detectar quando esta conectado numa rede de internet pelo plugin mas não consigo verificar se nesta rede conectada esteja com internet ou não, alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe o plugin citado na própria documentação: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/ para instalar navegue até a pasta do projeto com `cd` e execute os comandos, como no exemplo:

```
cd /home/user/projeto
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
npm install --save @ionic-native/network
```

Então no `src/app/app.module.ts` adicione aos providers, exemplo:

```
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';

...

@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    Network
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Então aonde for usar o módulo faça isso:

```
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';

constructor(private network: Network) { }

...

let disconnectSubscription = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
    console.log('Desconectado da internet');
});

let connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
    console.log('Conectado a internet!');
});
```

Se quiser parar os observadores use:

```
disconnectSubscription.unsubscribe();
connectSubscription.unsubscribe();
```

Note que não é porque você esta conectado a uma rede ou rede móvel que significa que teu provedor esta lhe enviando internet (lhe provendo), um teste mais simples seria usar `HttRequest` e checar se você consegue acessar qualquer url do serviço que interessa a sua aplicação.

Por exemplo (é em php mas pode adaptar facilmente) criaria uma página simples que retornaria qualquer coisa, por exemplo a palavra `success`:

```
<?php
echo 'success';
```

Então o teste seria algo como:

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';

constructor(private http: HTTP) {}

...

this.http.get('http://meu-site.com/status.php', {}, {})
  .then(response => {
      if (response.data === 'success') {
          console.log('Serviço disponível');
      }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Serviço indisponível');
    console.log("status:", error.status);
    console.log("descritivo:", error.error);
    console.log("headers:", error.headers);

  });
```

Comment: Sim, eu já tinha pensando em fazer um request mas achei que poderia ter alguma outra solução, obrigado!

Comment: @JulianoSouza a ideia do request pode ser usada até para checar outros serviços, tipo no lado do servidor checar se o banco de dados esta disponivel, ou até outras dependencias, ai retornaria um `success`, isso já checaria a internet e o teu servidor ao mesmo tempo, veja a edição da resposta.